# Редирект php/htaccess

Tags: php

Приветствую!
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать редирект с картинок на htaccess то есть заходим по site.ru/1.jpg и нас перекидывает на site.ru

или как сделать на php что бы при заходе на site.ru/1.php показывало картинку и через 5 секунд редиректило на site.ru
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На .htaccess вы никак не организуете редирект с задержкой. Стало быть есть такие варианты:

**1) Простой редирект всех картинок на корень сайта:**

```
# код для .htaccess
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule [^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|png) http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

**2) Редирект по условию с задержкой:**

```
# код для .htaccess
# направляем все запросы на index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

В самом начале файла index.php соорудите нечто такое:

```
<?php
$sec = 5;                              // через сколько секунд редиректить
$go_to_url = 'http://site.ru';         // куда редиректить
$pattern = '@[^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)@'; // по какому условию (все картинки)

// условие редиректа (если запрашивается картинка...)
if (preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    // важно! сначала устанавливаем заголовок
    header("refresh:{$sec}; url={$go_to_url}");

    // и только потом выводите, что вам нужно.
    echo "test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> заходим по site.ru/1.jpg и нас перекидывает на site.ru

с .htaccess давно в последний раз бодался, но вроде так:

```
RewriteRule 1\.jpg / [r=302]
```

> site.ru/1.php показывало картинку и через 5 секунд редиректило на site.ru

1. Написать простенький javascript, который через пять секунд перекинет пользователя

//

```
setTimeout(function(){location.href = '/';}, 5000);
```

//

1. Использовать тег meta. Это крайний метод, потому что поисковики его ненавидят.

//

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=site.ru">
```

//

Comment: спасибо,но htaccess не работал

Comment: @still-rise, в R=302 точно должна быть большая R, но может что еще напутал, а апача под рукой нет.

Comment: с большой R тоже не работает,ну ладно,спасибо за php)
htaccess всё ещё актуален.